# How to print line number of error that is inside a function using except in Python?

Tags: python, exception

I want to print an error's line number and error message in a nicely displayed way. The follow is my code, which uses *linecache*:

```
import linecache

def func():
    if xx == 1:
        print('ok')

try:
    func()
except:
    exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
    f = tb.tb_frame
    lineno = tb.tb_lineno
    filename = f.f_code.co_filename
    linecache.checkcache(filename)
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
    print_('ERROR - (LINE {} "{}"): {}'.format(lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj))
```

However, this only gives where the `func()` is called:

`ERROR - (LINE 8 ""): name 'xx' is not defined`

Is there a way to print the line number where the error actually occured, which should be Line 4? Or even better, can I print Line 8 and then trace back to line 4? For example, if I do not use `try - except`, the code:

```
def func():
    if xx == 1:
        print('ok')

func()
```

will give me the following error message, which is much better to locate the error:

```
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 2, in func
NameError: name 'xx' is not defined. Did you mean: 'xxx'?
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here, but you could use `except Exception as e: print(e)` to trace an error that occured in your `try` block.

Comment: Thank you but this will only print the error message without the line number of the error. I want both the error message and the line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `traceback` and `sys` modules to get advanced traceback output like you are wishing for.

Here is an example:

```
import traceback
import sys

def func():
    zeroDivide = 1 / 0

try:
    func()

except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc()) # This line is for getting traceback.
    print(sys.exc_info()[2]) # This line is getting for the error type.
```

Output will be:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b:\abc\1234\pppp\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    func()
  File "b:\abc\1234\pppp\main.py", line 7, in func     
    zeroDivide = 1 / 0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks just ```print(traceback.format_exc())``` can already give me what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the traceback module to get the line number of the error,

```
import traceback

def function():
    try:
        # code 
    except:
        tb_list = traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])
        line_number = tb_list[-1][1]
        print("An error occurred on line:", line_number)
```

You can use the `traceback.extract_tb()` function. This function returns a list of traceback objects, each of which contain information about the stack trace. The last element of this list, `tb_list[-1]`, holds information about the line where the exception occurred. To access the line number, you can use the second element of this tuple, `tb_list[-1][1]`. This value can then be printed using the `print()` function.

Answer (score 0):

To get the line number as an int you can get the traceback as a list from `traceback.extract_tb()`. Looking at the last item gives you the line where the exception was raised:

```py
#soPrintLineOfError2
import sys
import traceback

def func():
    if xx == 1:
        print('ok')

try:
    func()
except Exception as e:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    ss = traceback.extract_tb(tb)
    ss1 = ss[-1]
    print(ss1.line)
    print(ss1.lineno)
```

Output:

```
if xx == 1:
6
```